# modify syntax tree, then get updated semantic model

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm trying to modify syntax tree and then get semantic model updated. Here is what I have so far:

```
var tree = Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp.SyntaxTree.ParseCompilationUnit(code);
var compilation = Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp.Compilation.Create(
                        "MyCompilation",
                        syntaxTrees: new[] { tree },
                        references: new[] { mscorlib });
var semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);
...
var oldStatementNode = (parent as ExpressionStatementSyntax); //some SyntaxNode in the tree
var oldExpressionNode = oldStatementNode.Expression;
var newExpressionNode = Syntax.ParenthesizedExpression(oldExpressionNode);
var newRootNode = tree.GetRoot().ReplaceNode(oldExpressionNode, newExpressionNode);

var semanticInfo = semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(newExpressionNode); //throws exception "Syntax node is not within syntax tree"
```

If I try to call `semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);` or even make new compilation with `tree` before calling `GetTypeInfo()` - same exception.

So how do I get updated `SemanticModel`?
(Of course I could get modified source and do everything from start with it, but I guess there is more efficient way).

I'm missing something obvious here I'm sure, perhaps there is a new syntax tree created somewhere?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Roslyn types are immutable, so you need to construct a new `SyntaxTree` for your `newRootNode`, and then call `compilation.UpdateSyntaxTree` to get a new `Compilation`, and then you can call `newCompilation.GetSemanticModel(newTree)` to get a new `SemanticModel`.

Consider moving up to the Services level and using an ISolution instead.  Something like:

```
var doc = Solution.Create(SolutionId.CreateNewId()).AddCSharpProject("MyCompilation", "MyCompilation").AddMetadataReference(mscorlib).AddDocument("MyFile", code);

var semanticModel = (SemanticModel)doc.GetSemanticModel();
var root = (CompilationUnitSyntax)doc.GetSyntaxRoot();

SyntaxNode parent = null;
var oldStatementNode = (parent as ExpressionStatementSyntax); //some SyntaxNode in the tree
var oldExpressionNode = oldStatementNode.Expression;
var newExpressionNode = Syntax.ParenthesizedExpression(oldExpressionNode);
var newRootNode = root.ReplaceNode(oldExpressionNode, newExpressionNode);

doc = doc.UpdateSyntaxRoot(newRootNode);
semanticModel = (SemanticModel)doc.GetSemanticModel();
```